# Hashcat brute force - markov chains

Tags: hash, brute-force, password-cracking, hashcat

Hashcat uses Markov chains by default when using brute force mode. Do they really speed up the cracking since a randomly generated password normally has the same probability for every combination?

Comment: I googled "hashcat brute force markov" and got this as the top hit: https://hashcat.net/forum/thread-6245.html It explains how it works (with an example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of markov mode is not to crack randomly generated passwords - it's to crack passwords that are based on patterns.

So if you know that the passwords are securely randomly generated, you shouldn't use it.

Comment: If the goal is to exhaust the entire keyspace - run the attack to exhaustion - then whether or not you use Markov is immaterial. At the end of both Markov and non-Markov attacks, you've tried exactly the same candidates - just in a different order.

Comment: A markov attack is more computational intensive than a straight forward sequential brute-force, so it's likely to be slower. From some (not very rigorous) tests, I was seeing ~1670MH/s in markov mode vs ~1700MHs/ with it disabled (MD5, laptop GPU). But YMMV.

Comment: Very fair! Though that computational intensity should usually be negligible, because it's pretty heavily optimized. After 1 minute of runtime (waiting for the speed to stabilize), using hashcat 6.2.5 in an attack using an ?a x8 mask, attacking a single MD5 hash on 6 GTX 1080s, I see 116.5 GH/s (ETA 15h46m) using --markov-disable, and 115.9 GH/s (ETA 15h53m) using stock Markov. But those seven minutes might matter! :D And it may also scale differently on the total keyspace of the mask used, and where any static parts of the mask are used.

Comment: @RoyceWilliams yeah, I wouldn't expect it to be very significant. Interesting that you saw a smaller impact that I did on a more powerful rig - I would have expected the opposite. But your CPU is probably a lot faster (and has more cores) than the one in my laptop, so perhaps that's why. I imagine that there would be a similar (and possibly more noticeable) difference with John's incremental vs mask modes.